# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p6'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I try to use colab but it shows me the error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'p6'
but p6 is already installed. Windows 10
Can someone help me?

Comment: did you install the package with `pip` or `conda`? Did you try uninstall and reinstall the package?

Comment: I installed it with pip and I have also uninstalled and installed it again several times.